# How to update one cell when another changes?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a function `getRow()` which return a value from a certain range.

I then created another function `gtBF()` which return a value of a certain range from a different sheet. The row for the Range on the second function depends on the first function.

[image: Sheet Image]

Basically the value of C1 is copied from another sheet depending on the value of A1.

Both functions worked.

Currently I am trying to make C1 update every time I change the value of A1. How can I do that?

```js
function getBF() {
     var row = getRow();
     var sheetlampDP = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Lamp DP");
     sheetlampDP.activate();
     var bfValue = sheetlampDP.getRange(row,12).getValue();
     return bfValue;
}


function getRow(){
      var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet7").getRange(1,1).getValue();
      return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way to accomplish this is to change `getBF()` into a spreadsheet custom function that receives the value of `A1` (or any other cell) as a parameter `row`, instead of calculating it. That way, the spreadsheet service will take care of invoking it anew whenever `A1` is changed.

So, `C1` should contain:

```
=getBF( A1 )
```

...and your function becomes:

```js
function getBF( row ) {
  var sheetlampDP = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Lamp DP");
  var bfValue = sheetlampDP.getRange(row,12).getValue();
  return bfValue;
}
```